# Swift 2.0, UILabel and setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints

Tags: uibutton, uilabel, swift2

I have upgraded my xcode and now using Swift 2.0. I have an issue with all components which I set at runtime and used to rely on

`setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`

It seems that the method is no longer available and I had to comment out the code. As a result, all positioning is messed up....(impacting, buttons, labels, images shapes)

Any idea how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The method did changed in Swift 2.0

```
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints

Comment: @goggelj You're welcome! Any more problems, and you can google your old syntax with swift 2.0 e.g. `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints swift 2.0`

Comment: @goggelj if my answer is correct, mark it as solved, so it is not listed in unanswered questions!